# How to convert float raster to integer raster?

Tags: raster-calculator, landsat, qgis-2.4

I am using Normalize difference vegetation index (NDVI) derived from the landsat satellite band 3 and band 4 that have float values ranges from -1.0 to 1.0. I want to see the attribute table that is not possible in QGIS. 
I tried following expression in raster calculator of qgis but it did not work:

```
Int("float_raster" * 100)
```

the reason to multiply with 100 is to preserved the 2 digits at right level in attribute table that can be seen by again dividing by 100 in attribute table.

How can i scale see the better contrast in colour palette using qgis 2.40

Comment: How exactly did this raster calculation "not work"?

Comment: @whuber. It executed successfully and added in TOC but I can not open the attribute table even. Only shift of 2 digits to left can be seen in the raster but not truncated (rounded) that should be in integer value conversion as does in arcGIS raster calculator.

Comment: Can you not then use Translate (GDAL_Translate) with an output type of 16 bit integer (-ot Int16) to perform the rounding of the results?

Comment: @MichaelMiles-Stimson. Can you please little bit explain how can i do it if this is the solution to cope with the problem. I do not know how to translate ...

Comment: I didn't know you could get an attribute table with rasters in QGIS. I'm also unclear on how converting from a float to a integer will resolve this problem. QGIS is more than capable of displaying Float values. Try this: http://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/raster_mosaicing_and_clipping.html

Comment: Read http://wiki.tuflow.com/index.php?title=QGIS_Export_Raster_to_asc and in advanced options put *-ot Int16* instructions are here http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/69941/convert-32-bit-image-to-8-bit-image-in-qgis as 8 bit.

Comment: See this similar question and take a look at the answer of Kersten: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/146543/how-to-round-pixel-values-of-a-raster-in-qgis

Answer (score 2):

I think this has been answered here
[How to round pixel values of a raster in QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/146543/how-to-round-pixel-values-of-a-raster-in-qgis)

Basically, QGis Raster Calculator does not do float <-> int conversion. Use gdal_translate instead.

Comment: Or if you want to skip the step: Raster calculator -> gdal_translate, simply use gdal_cal (or the QGIS built in GDAL Raster Calculator) instead (I just added an answer on the quoted [question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/146543/how-to-round-pixel-values-of-a-raster-in-qgis/422614#422614) ).