Brightness Differences in DEM TIFF File
I created a DEM file with QGIS. File type TIFF. The files I use as sources are also TIFF. The file, which looks normal in QGIS, looks different when I look at it in other programs. When I open the DEM file with Photoshop or Windows Photo, the brightness almost disappears. The gray areas are getting dimmer. Is there any way I can change this?



Nope, this is a limitation of non-GIS software; don't expect your NoData value to be honored either. Beware of using Photoshop to edit georeferenced rasters, historically it was known to destroy georeference. If you want to view your DEM in a generic raster editor you should render it to an 8 bit greyscale or 24/32 bit RGB/RGBA which is something that these packages will understand https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/69941/convert-32-bit-image-to-8-bit-image-in-qgis.

You can style it in QGIS, right-click and export as rendered image. But this will create a new raster

You can do the same that QGIS is doing also with Photoshop. Find the minimum and maximum values from the histogram and stretch. You can use for example curves or levels https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/using/levels-adjustment.html.
